# Setting a rotation angle to match a BPM value

Tags: lua, rotation, trigonometry, cairo

I'm trying to set a rotation angle on some items to match the speed of a beats per minute counter. I have the items rotating, but I cannot get the rotation value to match the degrees per frame value I've worked out from the BPM.

Code is shown below. I've read up on trig, I have the placement of the dots on the circle down. They spread according to the number in the table. And I can get them rotating. But they rotate crazy fast.

In my head it should be simple: I have 16 notes in a sequence running at say 60bpm, which gives me 22.5 degrees between dots and they should rotate at 1.5 degrees per frame, at 15 frames per second, to rotate in time with the BPM clock. That's what I think I have set up but... they rotate much faster. I've manually put in various values but it isn't matching up.

```
local SCREEN_FRAMERATE = 15
local angleRot  -- the gap between the dots, based upon the number of dots / 360
local rotateSpeed  -- the speed in degrees per second we need to rotate so the dots align with the sounds
local bbppmm  -- the beats per minute of the track



function init()
  -- OTHER CODE HERE


    -- set initial animation properties
  angleRot = (360 / initSequence.length)  -- set the offset between dots
  rotateSpeed = (angleRot/SCREEN_FRAMERATE)  -- work out the degrees per frame we need to rotate


  -- we use a metro to trigger n times per second (SCREEN_FRAMERATE)
  screen_refresh_metro = metro.init()
  screen_refresh_metro.event = function()
    angleRot = angleRot+1
    redraw()
  end
  screen_refresh_metro:start(1/SCREEN_FRAMERATE)
end



-- drawing the graphical interface
function redraw()
  screen.clear()

    screen.level(4)
    screen.rect(0,0,128,64)
    screen.fill()

    screen.level(1)
    screen.circle(64,32,11)
    screen.stroke()

    for i=1,initSequence.length do
    if initSequence.data[i] > 0 then
      screen.circle(
        math.cos((angleRot + rotateSpeed)*i)*11 + 64,  -- angle * radius + offset from zero
        math.sin((angleRot + rotateSpeed)*i)*11 + 32,  -- this line and the above place the circles on the larger circle
        initSequence.data[i] + (freqs[i]/600)  -- this line make the sequence circles the sizes they are
      )
    screen.fill()
    end
  end
    screen.update()
end
```

I expect the dots to rotate at the speed of the BPM, so at 60bpm 22.5 degrees per second.

I get much faster rotation speeds, although it goes so fast the log can't keep up and it could just be random.

Answer (score 1):

Like an idiot I didn't convert degrees to radians first, correct code is:

```
math.cos(math.rad(angleRot)*i)*11 + 64,  -- angle * radius + offset from zero
math.sin(math.rad(angleRot)*i)*11 + 32,  -- this line and the above place the circles on the larger circle
```

Comment: consider deleting your posts. this is a small mistake in a very specific piece of code. it's unlikely to be useful to anyone else.